# Can't make pandas group by timeframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

thanks in advance for any input....

I'm trying to group some temperature readings together so I can compare two sets of readings. Below I'm trying to do it for a minute, but it doesn't matter if it's an hour.

The data seems to come through OK, just won't group properly. It just lists out all the temperature readings (many per minute).

The data is here : https://github.com/uilfut/pi_code/blob/master/tinydb_environment.json

'date_time' is the datetime column

'tempC' is the temperature column

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
with open('/home/data.json') 
as f:
    data = json.load(f)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({(i, j): data[i][j] for i in data.keys() 
for j in data[i].keys()}, orient='index')
df['data_source'] = df.index.droplevel(level=1)
df.index = df.index.droplevel(level=0)

df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'])

# this next line doesn't work - 
df.set_index('date_time').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='T, min')['tempC'].mean()

print(df.head(10))
```

I also tried

```
# df['time'] = df['date_time'].dt.time
# df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('5Min'))['tempC'].mean().dropna()
# df.set_index('date_time').groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1hour'))
['tempC'].mean().dropna()
# df.set_index('date_time').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='T, min'))
['tempC'].mean()
# df.set_index('time').resample("H").mean()
# df.set_index('date_time').resample('5min', how=np.mean)
```

Hope it's something easy for someone!

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `groupby` line is missing a `)`, and pandas 0.22 doesn't recognize the frequency `T, min`. Try this:

```
df.set_index('date_time').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='min'))['tempC'].mean()
```